# Visual Studio Intellisense doesn't recognise C#9 features

Tags: visual-studio-2019, c#-9.0

I'm using the latest version of VS2019 (16.8.4), and have just installed the .Net 5.0.1 SDK as I want to start using C#9 features.

However VS Intellisense doesn't recognise any of the new stuff, even though a program builds and runs fine.

Does anyone know how to get VS Intellisense to recognise C#9 features?

As an example, I created a console app project (called ConsoleApp2), targeting .Net 5.0, with a class that uses an init only setter.

The class is simply

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string TestProp { get; init; }
    }
}
```

and the startup code is

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testClass = new Class1 {TestProp = "test value"};
            Console.WriteLine(testClass.TestProp);
        }
    }
}
```

This will compile and run fine from VS, but Intellisense doesn't recognise what an init only setter is, and complains that "A property without setter or inaccessible setter cannot be assigned to". In fact it won't even show you the property name when you attempt to initialise the object.

FWIW, I have enabled the "Use previews of the .Net Core SDK" option in Tools | Preview Features, and restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem wasn't with native Visual Studio Intellisense, but with ReSharper.

I had ReSharper 2020.2.4 installed, but you have to go to 2020.3 to be compatible with C#9.0.

After I upgraded to ReSharper 2020.3.2, the Intellisense in Visual Studio worked correctly.

Comment: I am tempted to upvote this, but also to downvote the question because it is only a temporal issue.

Comment: @AndrewMorton True, but if I can save one person the several hours of effort it took me to resolve the issue, then I'm happy.